# Why is the command history only saved on exit

Tags: bash, terminal, history, command-history

I am trying to save a different history file per tab / terminal but I cannot manage to save it immediately after a command is run. The history is just saved when I run "exit".

This is a problem as what I want to achieve is to have a copy of the history in case the terminal or the computer crashes.

After looking around the internet, this is what I have in my .bashrc file:

```
export HISTFILE="$HOME/HISTORIES/bash_history_$(basename $(tty))_$(date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S_%Z')"
export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
export HISTFILESIZE=10000
export HISTSIZE=10000
shopt -s histappend
PROMPT_COMMAND=$(history -a; $PROMPT_COMMAND)
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the directory `$HOME/HISTORIES` exist? If not create it.

Comment: Of course it exists...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason that I cannot understand, this works:

```
export HISTFILE_NEW="$HOME/HISTORIES/bash_history_$(basename $(tty))_$(date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S_%Z')"
export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
export HISTFILESIZE=10000
export HISTSIZE=10000
shopt -s histappend
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -w $HISTFILE_NEW; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

While this, doesn't

```
export HISTFILE="$HOME/HISTORIES/bash_history_$(basename $(tty))_$(date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S_%Z')"
export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
export HISTFILESIZE=10000
export HISTSIZE=10000
shopt -s histappend
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Of course, the first solution is slower than the theoretically good one (the second) because the whole history is saved every time that a new command is written.

Therefore, if anyone knows WHY this is the case and how could this be solved, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Only important thing is 
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -w"
I just put that and it works properly, actually used this 2 lines.
shopt -s histappend
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -w"

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning PROMPT_COMMAND incorrectly.  When you write

```
PROMPT_COMMAND=$(history -a; $PROMPT_COMMAND)
```

You are running 'history -a' (which produces no output), and then running $PROMPT_COMMAND (which during your startup scripts may be empty), and assigning the output of those two commands (the empty string) to PROMPT_COMMAND.  What you want is just:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'
```

If you want to append it to a currently existing command, do

```
PROMPT_COMMAND+="history -a${PROMPT_COMMAND+=; }$PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Comment: Thanks, but still not working. I have tried both things. The file is only saved when running exit.

Comment: What is the current value of PROMPT_COMMAND?  If it is `history -a`, what happens if you `tail $HISTFILE`?  Note that PROMPT_COMMAND does not run until after your command finishes, so you might prefer to put `history -a` in a debug trap that runs before a command.

Comment: The value of PROMPT_COMMAND is history -a. The $HISTFILE does not exist (as I have been saying from the beginning, it is only created when running exit), so tail on that variable returns a "cannot open" error. Can you explain the "debug trap" better?

Comment: You might try `PROMPT_COMMAND='touch $HISTFILE; history -a'`  Or `trap 'touch $HISTFILE; history -a' DEBUG`

Comment: Same. With either of those, the result is the same, The only difference is that now the $HISTFILE is there when I start a new terminal, but nothing is written until I exit.

Comment: So I am guessing this is impossible?

Comment: It's not at all impossible.  I split my history into separate files based on the pid of the shell using `history -a` in a debug trap, and then merge it into a common file with status info, current working directory, and some other meta-data in a PROMPT_COMMAND.  You need to do more debugging.  Have you tried printing any diagnostic info during your PROMPT_COMMAND?

Comment: Which version of bash are you running?

Comment: Thanks, but I eally do not know hot do do more debugging. The bas version is:

4.2.1(2) (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 1):

Answering the intent, rather than the literal question:

Look at using script.  This will give you commands and their output. Note this is not a panacea, as any commands that use cursor positioning are difficult to decipher later.

Name
script - make typescript of terminal session

Synopsis
script [-a] [-c COMMAND] [-f] [-q] [-t] [file]

Description
Script makes a typescript of everything printed on your terminal. It is useful for students who need a hardcopy record of an interactive session as proof of an assignment, as the typescript file can be printed out later with lpr(1).

If the argument file is given, script saves all dialogue in file. If no file name is given, the typescript is saved in the file typescript.

Options:

```
  -a'        Append the output to file or typescript, retaining the priorcontents.
```

-c COMMAND
Run the COMMAND rather than an interactive shell. This makes it easy for a script to capture the output of a program that behaves differently when its stdout is not a tty.
-f' Flush output after each write. This is nice for telecooperation: One person does 'mkfifo foo; script -f foo' and another can supervise real-time what is being done using 'cat foo'.

-q' Be quiet.

-t' Output timing data to standard error. This data contains two fields, separated by a space. The first field indicates how much time elapsed since the previous output. The second field indicates how many characters were output this time. This information can be used to replay typescripts with realistic typing and output delays.

The script ends when the forked shell exits (a control-D to exit the Bourne shell (sh(1)), and exit, logout or control-d (if ignoreeof is not set) for the C-shell, csh(1)).

Certain interactive commands, such as vi(1), create garbage in the typescript file. Script works best with commands that do not manipulate the screen, the results are meant to emulate a hardcopy terminal.
...

Search "man script" on google.  If you have a particular OS include that.  This is the linux version but close to identical versions exist for *BSD, Mac.  Probably windows ports are out there too.

Comment: Not really very useful, but thanks for the effort. I just want the history of the commands I run, not the outputs. And I do not want to introduce more layers of complexity in something that should be easy.